# Has `dgeqrfp` been removed from LAPACK on macOS?

Tags: macos, lapack

Has `dgeqrfp` been removed from the Apple supplied LAPACK library?

```
> A % pwd
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A
> A % nm -gU *.dylib | grep dgeqr
000000000010ff2c T _dgeqr2
000000000010ff2c T _dgeqr2_
00000000001100f0 T _dgeqrf
00000000001100f0 T _dgeqrf_
```

Note: macOS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76).

Comment: It's not on my 10.15.4 Catalina system and it's not even on my 10.12.6 Sierra system. The [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/wiki/Dropping-support-for-Accelerate) folks don't paint a rosy picture for macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The scipy story combined with LAPACK missing from Apple's documentation tells me that LAPACK is not a priority at Apple. I am still puzzled why LAPACK is the only part of Accelerate not documented. Changes to LAPACK is therefore not documented anywhere. Maybe - but just maybe - the problem is related to the release notes from Catalina 10.15 "macOS frameworks are now thinned for the x86-64 architecture?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate?language=objc

Comment: Definitely thinned and I think it's because their priorities are pointing them to other fryable fish. After being embedded with macOS for many years, I would say they have only minor secondary interest in things not related to media production user experiences. Certainly, many low level operations require high performance computation but I believe those things are not what most macOS media production developers deal with every day.

Answer (score 1):

It is not in my Catalina either, but you can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install another version of the library:

```sh
brew install lapack
```

I do not have experience with the lib, so let me know if this helps you in your problem. :)